# Fabric js load svg from url missing properties

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I'm trying to use `loadSVGfromURL` and everything fine, but I have some problems with text.

If i'm trying to load text some properties like `font-family`, `fill`, etc... are not loaded. The text is loaded, but with default properties: black `color`, and Times new roman `font`.

Here is my code:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(img.src, function(objects, options) {
    var tmpobj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    canvas.setDimensions({
        width : tmpobj.width,
        height : tmpobj.height
    });
    //canvas.clear();
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
        //var obj = new fabric.Object({ padding: 0 });
        var obj = objects[i];
        if (obj.get('type') == 'text') {
            var text = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
                fontFamily : obj.get('fontFamily'),
                left : obj.get('left'),
                top : obj.get('top'),
                text : obj.get('text'),
                oCoords : obj.get('oCoords'),
                fontSize : obj.get('fontSize'),
                height : obj.get('height'),
                width : obj.get('width'),
                fill : obj.get('fill')
            });
            obj = text;
        }
        obj.padding = 0;
        obj.setCoords();
        canvas.add(obj);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
})
```

Comment: Could you provide some live example ? JSFiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1mcxn7um/

Comment: here is svg fie wich i used to test. If you open it in browser one string will be different color from others, but if you load with fiddle every string will be the same color https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-XQpJWb-678STYtVFhtTFY3eWs/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is missing TSPAN support in fabricjs.

The svg looks like this:

```
<text x="32" y="40" class="cls-1"><tspan class="cls-2">riev</tspan></text>
  <text x="158" y="211" class="cls-1"><tspan class="cls-3">0999989878</tspan></text>
  <text x="96" y="120" class="cls-1"><tspan class="cls-2">Platon</tspan></text>
```

The information class="cls-2" and class="cls-3" does not get parsed because the tspan are discarded.

You can modify the svg like this:

```
<text x="32" y="40" class="cls-1 cls-2"><tspan >riev</tspan></text>
  <text x="158" y="211" class="cls-1 cls-3"><tspan >0999989878</tspan></text>
  <text x="96" y="120" class="cls-1 cls-2"><tspan >Platon</tspan></text>
```

to get it parsed.

Comment: How can I modify every svg automatically? Can i just write simple scipt to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

I have added this 
 var svg = doc;
for (var i = 0; i < svg.childNodes.length; i++) {

```
      if (svg.childNodes[i].tagName == "text") {
          for (var j = 0; j < svg.childNodes[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
              if (svg.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].tagName == "tspan") {
                  for (var k = 0; k < svg.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].classList.length; k++)
                  {
                      var tmpClassName = svg.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].classList[k];
                      svg.childNodes[i].classList.add(tmpClassName);
                  }



              }
          }
      }
  }
```

in the

```
fabric.parseSVGDocument
```

function to add my tspan styles to text styles